# Why a company can have one stock on NASDAQ and one stock on OTC?

Tags: equities, exchange

ATRO is traded on NASDAQ.

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ATRO

ATROB is traded on OTC.

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ATROB

I don't understand why a company has one stock on NASDAQ and one stock on OTC. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 4):

**Astronics Corporation (ATRO) has two types of issued stock: Common stock and Corporate Class B stock.**

*The common stock (ATRO)* found on NASDAQ is the "standard" type of equity stock that gives you a 1 to 1 vote to share basis (*usually you get one vote per share owned, which is the case for ATRO*).

*The corporate class B stock (ATROB)* found on the OTC market is a second type of stock that gives you more company votes per share.

**The description of this issued [company proxy vote](https://materials.proxyvote.com/default.aspx?docHostID=299844) describes the differences quite well:**

> [...] Astronics was initially formed with one class of common stock (“Common Stock”). In 1987, the
> Company’s shareholders voted to adopt a second class of common stock, called Class B Stock.
> In addition, the Board of Directors proposed appropriate amendments to the Company’s
> Certificate of Incorporation for the additional class of stock, which were also approved by the
> shareholders. **As a result, Astronics has two classes of stock: Common Stock with one vote per share, and Class B Stock with ten votes per share.**

---

The issued document also describe how a transfer/sale of class B stock will be converted to common stock (*with no cost to the shareholder*) and lose the rights or entitlements associated with the Class B Stock. As is also written on the **[company FAQ](https://investors.astronics.com/company-information/faq)** there is "no market" for the Class B stock and thus the market will be specified as OTC, whereas the common stock is traded on NASDAQ.

Comment: Hi @user11980328. Did my answer help you or is there anything else you need to get clarified? If the answer above solved your issue, would you then please consider accepting it? :-) The same goes for [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70310/51407). Otherwise, give me some feedback, and I'll change my answer(s) accordingly.