# Definition of wilder's moving average

Tags: equities, technical-analysis

https://www.marketvolume.com/technicalanalysis/wildersvolatility.asp

I see this page describes wilder's moving average. But the first step `ATR = SMA(TR)` is not clear. How many periods should be used to compute this simple moving average? Should it be N?

````
...
Step #2: Apply the moving average to the defined TR.

ATR = SMA(TR)

Wilder uses simplified formula to calculate Average of True Range:

ATR = Wilder's Volatility = ((N-1) x Previous ATR + TR) / N
...
```
````

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, the SMA should be computed with $N$ periods in your situation:

In the original book of **[Wilder, J. W. (1978). *New concepts in technical trading systems.*](https://books.mec.biz/tmp/books/218XOTBWY3FEW2CT3EVR.PDF)** the author writes the following about the Volatility Index Indicator (**see p. 21 (bottom)**):

> In order for the range to be a meaningful tool as a measure of volatility, more than one day's range must be considered. The answer is to consider an **average** of the true range made per day over a number of days. A volatility indicator will be fast or slow, depending on the number of days used to obtain the average daily true range. **How many days should be used to obtain the average daily true range?** After extensive testing, I have found that about **14 days** gives the best indicator of volatility to use for the Volatility Index Indicator.

In conclusion, he recommends the average true range (ATR) **to be computed with a period of 14 days (ie. a 14-day SMA) which is equivalent to $N$ in your situation**.

---

This can be further seen, since he defines the Volatility Index Indicator on *p. 22* as:

$$
VI_{today} = \frac{13 \cdot VI_{previous} + TR_1}{14},
$$
where $TR_1$ is today's true range. This is equivalent to $N=14$ in your specified formula.